# Failure to find Session table using session_id with swfupload

Tags: php, swfupload

I have a problem with swfupload sessions.

I set the session_id in a form variable, and it successfully goes in the form POST. When I get this post and set the session by `session_id($_POST["session_id"])` I have a good session_id (because I checked this) but I don't have any variables in the `$_SESSION` table.

On my home computer this works fine, on the server it doesn't.

Should I check some of the PHP session settings?

Comment: Can you show the code that you use to set the session ID?

Answer (score 0):

Try http://valums.com/ajax-upload/ instead, it doesn't require Flash.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you may be encountering a [long-running Flash bug](http://bugs.adobe.com/jira/browse/FP-1044). The traditional way to work around it is to append a GET variable to the upload url that has the session in it, then take that and manually set it to be the session on the server-side.

It is hard to give an example of the best way to do it for your particular situation, but if you google '[flash upload cookie](http://www.google.ca/#hl=en&expIds=17259,18168,24472,26637,27147,27404&xhr=t&q=flash+upload+cookie&cp=17&pf=p&sclient=psy&aq=0&aqi=&aql=&oq=flash+upload+cook&gs_rfai=&pbx=1&fp=a895b078aa59531d)', you will find multiple solutions for php.